# playframework, is there a Validation.clearAfterRenderGet

Tags: playframework

I seem to be running into a weird anomoly in playframework

http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/ac1f48fa4c417b79

I have a form and a field with a url in it http://alvazan.com and when I post it, the oval validation is FINE and returns ZERO errors and then I do the Validation.keep to make sure errors are ketp until the GET request.  The GET request cannot clear the errors or they don't show up in the render call.  I want them cleared AFTER the render call.

1. I can't call clear in the POST because some validation is done before my method because of the annotations I use there.

How does this work exactly as something is not quite right in my implementation and is there a clearAfterRenderingGetRequest which would be the perfect method for this inside the get of any posted form(in fact, I thought flash would just clear automatically but Validation errors are not part of flash?)

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the calls to methods automatically always do redirect and my post is calling a render method(copy from examples) which I did not know does NOT do a redirect, so it would keep the errors in flash for the next GET which does not happen as the body is sent back in response to the post(which is usually a bad thing) and then on the next GET, my errors are the re and Validation.hasErrors gets those errors from flash causing the issue.

so, if you use render in your post, you don't call Validation.keep nor params.flash from what I understand or call another get method that you have.

for some reason, when I tried just changing render to redirect, my stuff just threw some platform exception which seemed weird so I could not use redirect method for some reason as I would prefer to stay more REST compliant here where http POST returns a 303 redirect to GET the next page even if that page is itself with errors.